# How can I choose an element's dataset based on a function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to pass a variable through a function and then let that variable decide which data from the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) will be used.

I pass through the element to target, the data within the `dataset` I want to check, and finally `true/false`.

```
function checkTileData(tile, data, bool)
{
    let dest = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number="'+tile+'"]');

    if (dest[0].dataset.data == bool) {
        return "yes!";
    } else {
        return "no";
    }
}

console.log(checkTileData(25,"passable",true));
```

I'm trying to check if the `data-passable` attribute is equal to `true`. Here is the target element:

```
<div class="tile" data-tile="floor" data-number="25" data-passable="true" data-row="3" data-col="5"></div>
```

Yet the function always returns `"no"`, even with `data-passable="true"` on the target element. Thanks.

Comment: Do you receive any errors through any console?

Comment: if you do console.log(typeof dest[0].dataset.data), do you get a string or boolean?

Comment: According to the specs all dataset values are converted to string so you need to test "true" or "false": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: @davidKo oddly it comes up as undefined, but dest[0] definitely exists on the page with a data attribute set to "passable". If it helps I'm hosting this on www.erdesigns.co.uk 

Comment: @Synthetx I'm passing through "true" now but still undefined. That was no doubt one of the problems though! (thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the property of an object when the property that you want to access is stored in a variable, for example, like:

```
dest[0].dataset[data]
```

Then, you need to notice that all the values stored on the `dataset` object are `strings`, so you can't compare they directly with a boolean value.

```js
function showTileData(tile)
{
    let dest = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number="'+tile+'"]');

    for (const key in dest[0].dataset)
        console.log(dest[0].dataset[key], typeof dest[0].dataset[key]);
}

showTileData(25);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<div class="tile" data-tile="floor" data-number="25" data-passable="true" data-row="3" data-col="5"></div>
```

Instead, you can pass a string on the `bool` variable, as

```
checkTileData(25,"passable","true")
```

## Example:

```js
function checkTileData(tile, data, bool)
{
    let dest = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number="'+tile+'"]');

    if (dest[0].dataset[data] == bool)
        return "yes!";
    else
        return "no";
}

console.log(checkTileData(25, "passable", "true"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<div class="tile" data-tile="floor" data-number="25" data-passable="true" data-row="3" data-col="5"></div>
```

## Alternative:

However, there is an alternative to do all the checks inside the `querySelectorAll()` method. In the next example, I'm going to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
function checkTileData(tile, data, bool)
{
    let dest = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-number="${tile}"][data-${data}="${bool}"]`);
    return (dest.length ? "yes!" : "no");
}

console.log(checkTileData(25, "passable", true));
console.log(checkTileData(25, "row", 22));
console.log(checkTileData(25, "col", 5));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<div class="tile" data-tile="floor" data-number="25" data-passable="true" data-row="3" data-col="5"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried both methods and can confirm they work! Must say the alternative is a great way to tackle this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `dest[0].dataset[data]` instead of `dest[0].dataset.data`
and cast your bool variable to string`bool.toString()`

**Why?**

`data` is a dynamic property, and to call it you need to use brackets `[]`

An object has 2 ways of calling their properties:

- Using `.` when you know the specific property called
- Using `[]` when you have an expression (i.e a variable with the property name)

When using `dataset` properties, these are evaluated as strings.

```js
function checkTileData(tile,data, bool){
    var dest = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number="'+tile+'"]');
    if (dest[0].dataset[data] == bool.toString()){
        return "yes!";
    } else {
        return "no";
    }
}

console.log(checkTileData(25,"passable",true));
```

```html
<div class="tile" data-tile="floor" data-number="25" data-passable="true" data-row="3" data-col="5"></div>
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)  I would suggest adding a link to the reference docs as it's well explained in there too (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! After updating the code it's actually constantly returning "yes!" even on tiles where passable="false". Not sure where it thinks the "true" is coming from if it's looking directly at the passable data attribute!